# Empty BIT values in MySQL version 5.5.32-log

Tags: mysql, bit, sqldatatypes, mysql-5.5

I am trying to insert a record in a table, but the BIT column never takes a value and is always empty.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (c1 BIT);
INSERT INTO foo (c1) VALUES (b'1');
```

What I have already tried: BIT(1), b'1', 0b1, TRUE, 1, '1'.

MySQL Version: 5.5.32-log

I let it pass and used BOOLEAN datatype, but I want to know what was wrong.

Comment: try CREATE TABLE foo (c1 BIT(1)); see what you get

Comment: The code as specified works on MySQL 5.1.41, so while I don't have an answer, it could be caused by changes between MySQL 5.1.41 and 5.5.32.

Comment: @Nick In my test it defaults to `BIT(1)`. I think this is a bug in the way the `mysql` command line utility displays bits, it works correctly at sqlfiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ec9bc/1

Comment: And `select c1 = b'1'` gives me the correct answer.

Comment: @Barmar 5.5.32-log is not available on sqlfiddle so we can test this on that version here.

Comment: Read the bug report linked in from the duplicate question, it's marked "Won't fix".

Comment: The bug report was against 5.0.17 and I reproduced it in 5.1.63. Seems unlikely that it works correctly in 5.1.41.

Comment: @Barmar looks like a bug in the display. Select statements are correct and are as expected. But what is interesting is when I delete this row using phpMyAdmin, the SQL generated has a where clause: c1 = \' \'.

Comment: That's part of the display issue. Bits are converted to the equivalent binary string, so `b'1'` is being displayed as a character with ASCII code 1.

Comment: Can't reproduce it with sqlfiddle running version 5.5.32 See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8cf9/2/0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducable.

Answer (score 0):

For display, you can convert the BIT column into another datatype, like INT.

To convert to INT, you can add 0, e.g.

```
SELECT c1+0 AS c1 FROM foo ;
```